# Not Sending notify_user email. Templates made and parameters already added?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a simple working contact form that emails a specific person in a company possible customer information. However, the client also wants a confirmation sent to the potential customer when the customer submits the form containing a link and some other general info so that then can return to the "thank you" url, which has some helpful information.

How do you send two different emails at the same time to two a regular email address but also the email inputed in a form?

I doesn't seem you can use {email} to email the person who submitted the form.

I know now from research that you need three items filled out to email the user that submitted the form,

user_notification_template="Employee-Relocation-Form-Thank-You-Confirmation-Email"
notify_user="yes" 
user_email_field="email"

I also know that the templates need to be made. They are both made (the first one works) but I still after fiddling with this extension for hours get it to email the submitter/possible future customer. Can some find anything wrong with my form?

```
{exp:freeform:form
        form:id="employee-relocation-form" 
        collection="Employee Relocation Form"

    user_notification_template="employee-relocation-form-thank-you-confirmation-email"
    notify_user="yes" 
        user_email_field="email"

        return="www.mycompany.com/thankyou"
        admin_notify="employee@mycompany.com"
        admin_notification_template="employee-relocation-form"
    notify_admin="yes" 
        }

    <p><span>* </span>Indicates required field</p>

    <div>
        <label for="name">Name <span class="req">*</span></label><br>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""  class="validate[required] text-input">
    </div>                  
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email <span class="req">*</span></label><br>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value=""  class="validate[required,custom[email]]">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="phone">Phone Number</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="">
    </div>

    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" >

{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter 'collection' is no longer used in the latest version of Freeform, therefore, collection="Employee Relocation Form" should be form_name="Employee Relocation Form", as does form:id > form_id.

I always read through this link below when upgrading from old Freeform forms

http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/upgrade_3.x-4.x/